# How to see specify class list in spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to check out specify class in spring-boot.
Because I am curious about what class is specified on CrudRepository interface.
this is a interface. But I am not having specifyied class

```
@Repository
public interface AnyRepository extends CrudRepository<Any, String> {

}
```

concretely, I want to check out save, findAll source of method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can debug the code and you will see the implementation of your class.

```
@Autowired
AnyRepository repo;
```

Add a checkpoint on below call and go inside this method or the method you have.

```
repo.findById(id);
```